# conda install r-essentials takes forever

Tags: r, anaconda

I am unable to install the r-base and r-essentials packages into my conda environment. Whenever I run

```
conda install -c r r-base r-essentials
```

I just get the `Solving environment` message for a good hour or more before I just exit out altogether. This even occurs when I create a brand new environment without any other packages before attempting to install r-base and r-essentials.

What is going on here and is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason there is a conflict when r-essentials and pip are in the same conda environment. You can solve it by creating a new environment that has the package directly:

```
conda create -n r_env -c r r-essentials
```

Answer (score 1):

Try that. `conda install -c conda-forge r r-essentials`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I just created the environment alone only with r-base. Then I tried installing r-essentials your way.

`conda create -n r_env r-base`

`conda activate r_env`

`conda install r-essentials`

But the last could not find compatible solver and was delaying even overnight.
I used `conda install -c conda-forge r r-essentials` and it worked this time - also took 20min or so. Thank you!